# What should be the maximum size of Call for a runtime

Tags: runtime, call, limit

There are unit tests in Polkadot and Kusama runtimes that fail if the `core::mem::size_of<Call>` is greater than 230 bytes. [Kusama](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/067c8a2847c841644d41d2df7c1cb137fdc8b014/runtime/kusama/src/tests.rs#L177), [Polkadot](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/067c8a2847c841644d41d2df7c1cb137fdc8b014/runtime/polkadot/src/lib.rs#L2174), [Substrate](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/279593d87f103fa5e10c9751a97b1584f3ad79d6/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L2155).

What exactly is this size of and how was the limit chosen? More importantly is there any risk in it being too large? In our Joystream runtime the size of Call is reaching 350 Bytes.

The test does suggest using `Box` to reduce the size but its not clear how to do this.

Any advise would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no hard science here, the number selected is [quite arbitrary](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/9418#discussion_r675313941).

[Clippy explains](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/#large_enum_variant) why we would want to do this best:

> > What it does
>
> Checks for large size differences between variants on enums.
>
> > Why is this bad?
>
> Enum size is bounded by the largest variant. Having a large variant
> can penalize the memory layout of that enum.
>
> > Known problems
>
> This lint obviously cannot take the distribution of variants in your
> running program into account. It is possible that the smaller variants
> make up less than 1% of all instances, in which case the overhead is
> negligible and the boxing is counter-productive. Always measure the
> change this lint suggests.
>
> For types that implement Copy, the suggestion to Box a variant’s data
> would require removing the trait impl. The types can of course still
> be Clone, but that is worse ergonomically. Depending on the use case
> it may be possible to store the large data in an auxillary structure
> (e.g. Arena or ECS).
>
> The lint will ignore generic types if the layout depends on the
> generics, even if the size difference will be large anyway.

I believe we specifically ran into memory allocation errors in the Wasm executor where we were WAY over-allocating memory for a `Call`, since some random variants were very large, and the memory allocator needs to handle the `Call` being those large variants.

~200 bytes was selected because [clippy also warns at this size](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/#large_enum_variant).

Comment: Thank you for this excellent explanation. I just have some followup questions. 1. There doesn't seem to be a way in Rust to get the size of individual variants to help identify which variant needs to be re-worked to reduce its size. How were you able to identify them. 2. How large was the call size which caused the WASM executor to cause it to fail with memory allocation errors. Thanks again.